# Arduino Command Line Interface - How to change boardsmanager.additional.urls

Tags: arduino-ide

I am building a Travis CI job to test my Arduino Library and it needs to install external board definitions.

Is there a way that I can set the boardsmanager.additional.urls from the command prompt like it would have been done in the Preferences window?

Or should I create preferences.txt file? (If so where does that live in a Linux environment)

Comment: The location of preferences.txt is shown near the bottom of the preferences page.  It takes two or three clicks to open it in gedit.

Answer (score 5):

Found the solution:

```
arduino --pref "boardsmanager.additional.urls=http://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json"
```

Comment: Note that since Arduino IDE 1.6.4 preferences set via `--pref` are only saved if you also use the `--save-prefs` option. See: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/build/shared/manpage.adoc#history